# how to make css div child width fit with div parent

Tags: html, css, height, width, pixel

```
<div class="parent" style="width:1287px;">
    <div class="child" style="width:1366px;"></div>
</div>
```

i have div parent with width 1287px and I want make div child with width 1366px fit to parent, how ?

Comment: The way your question is phrased, you want your bigger child to fit inside of a smaller parent?

Comment: yes, I want my bigger child to fit inside of a smaller parent. is it possible ?

Comment: Please explain what exact _behavior_ you want to see here, what you _mean_ by “fit”.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In this snippet here, there is a larger child inside of a smaller parent. Based on your question, unless it is not as clear as you think.

```css
.parent {
  max-width: 1287px;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.child {
  max-width: 1366px;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 2px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Here it is without the min/max widths:

```css
.parent {
  width: 1287px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.child {
  width: 1366px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but max-width or min-height its just for limit size not real size I think